# Can you use LetsEncrypt with Nginx and localhost?

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt

I didn't think you could use SSL with localhost but I came across this [Q&A which says you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946170/how-can-i-install-ssl-on-localhost-in-ubuntu).

I'm looking for similar instructions to do this nginx instead of apache.

I'm running:

```
sudo letsencrypt certonly -d localhost
```

Which returns `Requested domain localhost is not a FQDN`

Is what I want to do possible and if so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, using `letsencrypt` with `localhost` is not possible and actually doesn't make any sense, as `localhost` is by definition only reachable by yourself, in which case a self-signed cert is absolutely sufficient.

Comment: I'm trying to develop a microsoft word add-on and it needs SSL but I don't have a domain

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Get one, then. They're like $7. Or find a provider that gives out free subdomains like https://freedns.afraid.org/ and use that.

Comment: But it is possible with apache? Just not LetsEncrypt?

Comment: Getting a domain is easy and cheap. Also, as I said, self-signed certs are quite possible even with `localhost` - just not with `letsencrypt`, as they had no way to verify you and distinguish you from any of the billion other peoples having their own `localhost`.

Comment: lvh.me is a domain with itself and all wildcards pointing to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible with LE. Think through it for a bit: LE needs to verify domain ownership before they issue a signed certificate. How are they going to verify that you have control of "localhost"? Every single computer on the planet has a "localhost", so they cannot issue a certificate for this CN.

Comment: I appreciate the help but why is this a stupid question. If it's possible with 'sudo a2enmod ssl' one (who doesn't know how either work) would think LetsEncrypt would work too.

Comment: There is a very large difference between enabling SSL support in your web server and obtaining a signed certificate from a widely-trusted CA. You're conflating two completely different things here.

Comment: hmm I didn't realize that. I really just need the ability to serve over https because I get mixed source error when I use http://localhost. Thanks for your help.